# Remove sms notification in status bar

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm building an sms handling application. I'm trying to remove **only** the notification icon from status bar, if received sms contains previously defined text such as "ALERT". So if the notification sound is open, sound will play as usual.

I can't use [abortBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29) , because I want to store sms into the inbox. I don't want to delete it completely.

[cancel(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29) might work, but I don't know how to get id of notification that is created by native sms application of android.

I already tried [cancelAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll%28%29) since it is not my notification, it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance

**PS.** Maybe I can use abortBroadcast() to block the notification icon at status bar, and then I can put sms into inbox programmatically, but it doesn't sound like a good practice for a simple task.